# Count longest streak of heads

Tags: java

I have been stuck on this for weeks, I have no idea how to do this. I just want the longest streak of heads. I have tried countless times and I just don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
public class LongestStreak extends ConsoleProgram
{
public static final int FLIPS = 100;
int currentRun;
int runStart;
int maxRun;

public void run()
{
double heads = 0;
double tails = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < FLIPS; i++)
        {
        if(Randomizer.nextBoolean())
        {
            System.out.println("Heads");
            heads++;
            currentRun++; // use ++ in preference to +=1, and this should be before maxRun test
            if (maxRun < currentRun) {
                maxRun = currentRun;
                runStart = currentRun - i; // this will produce a 1-based position
            } else {
            currentRun = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Tails");
            tails++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(FLIPS);
}
```

}

Comment: You never print out the streak.  Instead, you print out the bounds of the loop.

Comment: You should consider resetting currentRun to 0 when a tails is flipped.

Comment: Ah, so I changed it to print out the maxRun but the maxRun seems to be just all of the heads. Like out of 100 flips, there was 51 heads. I don't want that.

Comment: Shouldn't you zero out `currentRun` in case you get tails?

Comment: Yeah I added the reset to currentRun

Comment: I think I'm getting closer

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if i understand your problem right, but here i have a solution, which will print you the longest streak within the 100 FLIPS

```
public static void run() {
    Random r = new Random();
    double heads = 0;
    double tails = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < FLIPS; i++) {
        if (r.nextBoolean()) {
            System.out.println("Heads");
            heads++;
            currentRun++;
            if (maxRun < currentRun) {
                maxRun = currentRun;
                runStart = currentRun - i;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Tails");
            tails++;
            currentRun = 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(FLIPS);
    System.out.println(maxRun);
}
```

Comment: anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LongestStreak extends ConsoleProgram
{
    public static final int FLIPS = 100;


    public void run()
    {

        int consecutiveHeads = 0;
        int maxRun = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < FLIPS; i++)
        {
            if(Randomizer.nextBoolean())
            {
                System.out.println("Heads");
                consecutiveHeads++;
                    if(maxRun <  consecutiveHeads)
                    {
                         maxRun = consecutiveHeads;
                    }


            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Tails");
                consecutiveHeads = 0;
            }
        }

                        System.out.println("Longest streak of heads: " + maxRun);
    }
}
```